# Extend the class that extends another class

Tags: sass

I have this:

```
.classOne {
    color: white;
}
.classTwo {
    @extend .classOne;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.classThree {
    @extend .classTwo; // problem here
    background-color: red;
}
```

I want .classThree to extend .classTwo, which implies that the props of .classOne are also passed to .classThree, but it, in reality, it does not happen.

**How can I achieve this? Should I extend .classOne and .classTwo in .classThree?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scss generates this css code:

```
.classOne, .classTwo, .classThree { // .classThree here
  color: white;
}

.classTwo, .classThree {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.classThree {
  background-color: red;
}
```

As you can see at line 1, `.classThree` inherits color property from `.classOne` and font-size from `.classTwo`. All works perfectly!